# Android : Load image from specific directory

Tags: android, image, gallery

I have a gallery that is displaying thumbnail images in custom directories. The gallery displays fine, but I am unable to open the full image by clicking the thumbnail. My [non functioning] click listener is below

```
    try {
        if (LoadImageFiles() == true) {
            GridView imgGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

            final ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(PersonMedia.this);
            imgGallery.setAdapter(ia);

                            // Set up a click listener
            imgGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        String imgPath = paths.get(position);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("filename", imgPath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                  }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("PersonMedia.LoadPictures", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Here is how the gallery is populated

```
//Declare a module level hashtable
private Hashtable<Integer, String> paths;



private boolean LoadImageFiles() {

try{
    mySDCardImages = new Vector<ImageView>();

    paths = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();

    fileCount = 0;

    sdDir = new File(imageDirectory);
    sdDir.mkdir();

    if (sdDir.listFiles() != null) 
    {
        File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();

        if (sdDirFiles.length > 0) 
        {               
            for (File singleFile : sdDirFiles) 
            {                   
                Bitmap bmap = decodeFile(singleFile);
                BitmapDrawable pic = new BitmapDrawable(bmap);

                ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(PersonMedia.this);                    
                myImageView.setImageDrawable(pic);
                myImageView.setId(mediaCount);      

                paths.put(fileCount, singleFile.getAbsolutePath());

                mySDCardImages.add(myImageView);

                mediaCount++;
                fileCount ++;
            }
         }
       }
     }
       catch(Exception ex){ Log.e("LoadImageFiles", ex.getMessage()); }

     return (fileCount > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using a hashtable to store the position and path of the images when the thumbnails are loaded. Below are the 2 pertinent code snippets

```
//Where the gallery is populated and the onclick is defined

private void PopulateGallery() {

    try {
        if (LoadImageFiles() == true) {
            GridView imgGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

            imgGallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(PersonMedia.this));

            // Set up a click listener
            imgGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        String imgPath = paths.get(position);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("filename", imgPath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                  }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("PersonMedia.LoadPictures", ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

```
//Where the images are loaded. You'll need to create a module level hashtable

private Hashtable<Integer, String> paths;

private boolean LoadImageFiles() {

try{
    mySDCardImages = new Vector<ImageView>();

    paths = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();

    fileCount = 0;

    sdDir = new File(imageDirectory);
    sdDir.mkdir();

    if (sdDir.listFiles() != null) 
    {
        File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();

        if (sdDirFiles.length > 0) 
        {               
            for (File singleFile : sdDirFiles) 
            {                   
                Bitmap bmap = decodeFile(singleFile);
                BitmapDrawable pic = new BitmapDrawable(bmap);

                ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(PersonMedia.this);                    
                myImageView.setImageDrawable(pic);
                myImageView.setId(mediaCount);      

                paths.put(fileCount, singleFile.getAbsolutePath());

                mySDCardImages.add(myImageView);

                mediaCount++;
                fileCount ++;
            }
         }
       }
     }
       catch(Exception ex){ Log.e("LoadImageFiles", ex.getMessage()); }

     return (fileCount > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your images have extensions, such as .jpg or .png? I'm not quite sure but it looks like you are looking for an image that is string version of your `personId`, without any file extension.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Also please post more details, such as the errors you are getting.

Updated answer below.

Use `View.setTag(Object)`, when you are adding items to your `ListView` (I am guessing).  You can call something like the following.

```
view.setTag("imgFile.jpg");
```

And then from inside of your onClickListener, just do this:

```
String img = (String) getTag();
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I haven't completely gotten my brain wrapped around URIs yet. What I'm passing into withAppendPath is the directory the actual image is stored in (each person has their own image directory). I thought the file name would be returned by the cursor.

Comment: The error I receive is : IllegalStateException : Unknown URL : content://media/external/images/media/CaseManager/3

Comment: What is the name of the image for case 3?

Comment: 2.jpg. I only know that because I name them before saving them and I can see it by opening the filesystem. I don't know how to extract the filename during the onclick event. (Pre cursor)

Comment: As an added note, I can make the image appear if I hard code the image name like so... Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CaseManager/" + Long.toString(personId) + "2.jpg".  Since I don't know the name of the file from clicking on the tumbnail I can't build the full path, therefore I'm trying to query the directory to get the file name.

Comment: Updated answer with possible solution

Comment: Please update your source code in your question to what you currently have in your project

Comment: I was able to get it working by using a hashtable to store the location and path of the files. Source code has been updated. Thank you for your help.